# How to wait for an API call using subscribe to finish in ngOnInit?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular6

Actual Log order:
('ngOnInit started') 
('after me aaya', this.policydetails) 
('Here', Object.keys(this.policy).length)

Expected Log order:
('ngOnInit started') 
('Here', Object.keys(this.policy).length)
('after me aaya', this.policydetails)

Component.ts file snippet below:

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit started');
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.getPoliciesService.getPolicyDetails(params.policyNo)
      .subscribe((data: PoliciesResponse) => {
        this.policy = data.data[0];
        this.flattenPolicy();
        console.log('Here', Object.keys(this.policy).length);
    });
    });

    this.makePolicyTable();

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('after me aaya', this.policydetails);
    const table = this.policydetails.nativeElement;
    table.innerHTML = '';
    console.log(table);
    console.log(this.table);
    table.appendChild(this.table);
    console.log(table);
  }
```

Service.ts file snippet below:

```
getPolicyDetails(policyNo) {
  const serviceURL = 'http://localhost:7001/getPolicyDetails';
  console.log('getPolicyDetails service called, policyNo:', policyNo);
  const params = new HttpParams()
    .set('policyNo', policyNo);
  console.log(params);
  return this.http.get<PoliciesResponse>(serviceURL, {params} );
}
```

JS file snippet corresponding to the API call below:

```
router.get('/getPolicyDetails', async function(req, res) {
    let policyNo = (req.param.policyNo) || req.query.policyNo;
    console.log('policyNo', typeof policyNo);
    await helper.getPolicyDetails({'policyNo' : policyNo}, 
        function(err, data) {
            console.log(err, data)
            if (err) {
                return res.send({status : false, msg : data});
            }
            return res.send({status : true, data : data});
    });
});
```

Can anyone please suggest where exactly do i need to async-await for expected log order?

Comment: getPolicyDetails you can call inside ngAfterViewInit only. No need of 2 life cycles

Answer (score 5):

If you want `this.makePolicyTable()` to be called only after the web request (`getPolicyDetails`) completes, then you should place that call inside of the `.subscribe()` block:

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log('ngOnInit started');
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.getPoliciesService.getPolicyDetails(params.policyNo)
      .subscribe((data: PoliciesResponse) => {
        this.policy = data.data[0];
        this.flattenPolicy();
        console.log('Here', Object.keys(this.policy).length);

        this.makePolicyTable();
      });
  });
}
```

You'll probably also want to move the table logic that's in `ngAfterViewInit()` inside the `subscribe()` block, too.

Basically, any logic that needs to wait for the asynchronous call to complete should be triggered inside the `.subscribe()` block. Otherwise, as you're seeing, it can be run before the web request gets back.

Finally, I would move this web service call into `ngAfterViewInit()` instead of `ngOnInit()`. Then you can be sure that the Angular components and views are all set up for you to manipulate them when the web service call completes.

Answer (score 0):

You could also set a flag variable to false in the component and then when async calls finishes set it to true and render the HTML based on that flag variable with *ngIf syntax.